# ´Prove that the circumcircles of two triangles are tangent to the sides of a triangle.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles

Let $ABC$  a isosceles triangle such that $AB=AC$ and consider a straight line $\ell$ thought by $A$ such that intersect the circumcircle of $ABC$ and the line $BC$ in $E$ and $D$
respectively.Prove that the circumcircles of the triangles  $DCE$ and $BDE$ are tangent to the sides $AC$ and $AB$ respectively.

I´m searching ideas about how do I should start to prove it.

I tried first do it by angles and show that $\angle ABD$ and $\angle ACD$ have mesure of $90^{\circ}$ but it fail since I can´t find a other angles that have a stronger relationship with my tarjet angles.
In addition I try show that the triangles $ABD$ and $ADC$ are
right triangles but I can´t show it.
In this point I don´t have more anymore ideas of how start the problem.

Any intuition or idea was helpful thanks in advice.

Comment: Hint: Create D' and E' By drawing a line through the midpoint of BC. Notice that ABE' is a right angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proof involving inversion, since it allows to "see" the claimed property in a breath. If inversion is not in the own avatar of geometric methods, there will be a simple translation using common means.

First of all, this is an Euclidean geometry problem, so a picture is an imperative.

[image: math stackexchange problem 4126234 inversion solution]

---

**Proof:** Consider the inversion with center $A$ and power $k^2:=AB^2=AC^2$ which thus invariates $B,C$ (and the circle centered in $A$ with radius $AB=AC$). It maps the circle $(ABC)$ through $B,C$ into a line through their transformed maps, which are also $B,C$, so it maps it into the line $BC$. Since $E$ (on the circle) transforms into $D$, we have:
$$
AD\cdot AE = k^2= AB^2\ ,
$$
and considering the power of the point $A$ w.r.t. the circle $(BDE)$, the above relation shows that the line $AB$ intersects "for the second time" (counting multiplicities) the circle $(BDE)$ again in $B$, so $AB$ is tangent to it.

By symmetry, the same property is valid for $C$. (Or rename, exchanging $B\leftrightarrow C$.)

$\square$

---

**Alternative proof:**

As said in the introduction, if the word *inversion* does not have a bind in the mind, then the following makes the above argument work in a common world. Let $l^*$ be the symmetry line of the triangle, $l^*\perp BC$, it intersects the circle, respectively $BC$ in the points denoted by $E^*$, and respectively $D^*$. Then $DD^*\perp AE^*$ and $E^*E\perp AE$, so $\Delta AEE^*\sim\Delta AD^*D$, which gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
AD\cdot AE &= AD^*\cdot AE^*\\
&=AB^2=AC^2\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
the second equality being seen either from a well known property of the height in $\Delta ABE^*$ with a right angle in $B$, or by letting $E$ take the special position $E=B$, when the corresponding $D$ becomes also $D=B$.

Now we can use again the (reciprocal) properties of the power of a point w.r.t. a circle as in the first proof. Or go as a pedestrian as follows.

From $AD\cdot AE=AB^2$ we obtain, building proportions, the similarity $\Delta ABE\sim \Delta ADB$ (of triangles with a common angle in $A$). Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{BAD} 
&=
\widehat{BDE}
- 
\widehat{DBA} 
\\
&=
\widehat{BDE} 
-
\widehat{BEA}
\\ 
&=\frac 12
(\overset\frown{BE} -  \overset\frown{BD})
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where in the last line we use measures of angles in the circle $(BDE)$. On the other side, the measure of the angle in $A$, exterior to this circle, built by the lines $AB$ and $ABE$ has a "similar formula". More exactly, if $B'$ is the second point of intersection of $AB$ with this circle, then we have for this angle the measure either
$\frac 12
(\overset\frown{B'E} -  \overset\frown{BD})$
or
$\frac 12
(\overset\frown{BE} -  \overset\frown{B'D})$.
Comparing, we get $B=B'$. This finishes the pedestrian proof.

$\square$

Answer (score 0):

Proving that the circumcircle of $\triangle DCE$ is tangent to $AC$ is equivalent to proving $\angle CDE=\angle ACE$. This is doable by simple angle chasing and applying properties of cyclic quadrilateral.

Once done, then $\angle BDE=\angle CDE=\angle ACE=\angle ABE$ and thereafter the circumcircle of $\triangle BDE$ is tangent to $AB$ by the argument mentioned earlier.